# Convergence of Minimum number of tosses to obtain $n$ heads

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose an unbiased coin is flipped independently infinitely many times. Let $T_n$ be the minimum number of flips to get $n$ heads. Show that $T_n/n \rightarrow c$ a.s. and compute $c$.

My approach: Let X_i(\omega) be the random variable such that, $X_i(\omega) = 1$ if the $i-th$ toss is heads and $0$ otherwise.

$P(X_i(\omega) = 1) = 1/2$ and $P(X_i(\omega) = 0) = 1/2$, for all $i = 1,2,3,...$

$T_n(\omega) = \inf_{M \geq n }\{M:\sum_{i = 1}^{M} X_i(\omega) = n$}.

How do I proceed from here on? I think the Strong Law of Large numbers needs to be used as I need to prove almost sure convergence.

Comment: The value $T_n$ can be viewed as the sum of $n$ i.i.d. times.

Comment: @Michael Is $c = 1$?

Comment: What would suggest $c=1$?  Note that $T_n/n$ has units of heads/flip, so $c=1$ would suggest...

Comment: @Michael $T_n/n$ should converge to $2$ i.e., number of tosses to obtain $n$ heads ~ $2n$.

Comment: So how do you prove that? (PS:  I see now I meant "flips per heads" instead of "heads per flip," but either way $c=1$ would suggest the coin always lands heads).